# How do you simplify this resistor circuit?

Tags: resistors

[image]

Is R3 + R4 in series, R1 + R2 in series and R12 + R34 in parallel, giving a total resistance of 8.5ohm correct?

EDIT:
Redrew with all the resistors vertically
[image]

So R1 and R2 are parallel, R3 and R4 are parallel R12 and R34 are in series, giving a total resistance of 7.96ohm?

Comment: No, that is not correct. I think you have the meaning of parallel and series the opposite way.

Comment: Actually, you have R1 || R2 in series with R3 || R4. The diagonal line is actually the middle point. Redraw it with diagonal line being a point rather than line and things become clear

Comment: Redraw it with all resistors vertical.

Comment: Use your eyes - redraw as transistor says. Where is R34 and R12?

Comment: 7.97 ohm or 7.968 ohm or 7.9676 ohm - accuracy can be important.

Comment: I think you need to better understand what parallel and series means. It is about current flow. When you start at one point and walk the circuit to another point and no branching occurs on the way, then all elements you walked are in series. When you can walk from one point to another by several different paths (not necessarily all possible paths)  with no branching in either path, the paths are parallel. No branching means current is constant along the way and this is essential.

Comment: 7+239/247 ohms.

Answer (score 3):

With the diagram redrawn, it becomes apparent that R1 and R2 are in parallel, and that R3 and R4 are in parallel.

So use the formula for parallel resistors to replace R1 and R2 with a single resistor R12.  Do the same with R3 and R4 to calculare R34.

Then you have R12 in series with R34.